# Instantly "locking" a record in multi-user Access environment

Tags: vba, ms-access

So, record-locking in Access is pretty awful. I can't use the built-in record locking because it locks a "page" of records instead of just the individual records (I've tried changing the settings for using record-level locking, but it's still locking a page instead of just one record), but even if I could get that working, it wouldn't solve my issue because the record doesn't lock until the user starts to make changes in the form.

The issue is, when two people open the same record, they can start making changes and both save (thus overwriting the earlier change). To make matters worse, there are listboxes on the form that link to other tables (keyed on an ID) and the changes they make to those tables are then overwritten by any change that comes after if they both opened the same record.

Long story short, I need to make sure it's impossible for two people to even *open* the same record at the same time (regardless of whether or not they've made any edits to it yet).

To do this, I added a field to the table which indicates if a record has been locked by a user. When they open a form, it sets their name in the field and other users who try to open that record get a notification that it's already locked. The problem is, this "lock" isn't instantaneous. It takes a few seconds for other users to "detect" that the record is locked, so if two people try to open the same record at roughly the same time, it will allow them both to open it. I've applied a transaction to the UPDATE statement that sets the lock, but it still leaves a short window wherein the lock doesn't "take" and two people can open the same record.

So, is there a way to make an UPDATE instantaneous (so all other users immediately see its results), or better yet, a robust and comprehensive way to lock records in an Access multi-user environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I finally figured out all of the issues contributing to this and worked out a solution.

The problem is multi-faceted so I'll cover the issues separately:

**First issue:** My custom locks weren't instantaneous. Even though I was using a transaction, there were several seconds after a lock was placed where users could still access the same record at the same time. I was using CurrentDb.Execute to UPDATE the record and Workspaces(0).BeginTrans for the transaction. For some reason (despite Microsoft's assurances to the contrary from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197654.aspx) the issue was that the transaction wasn't working when using the Workspaces object. When I switched to DBEngine.BeginTrans, the lock was instantaneous and solved my immediate problem.

The irony is that I almost always use DBEngine for my transactions but went with Workspaces this time for no reason, so that was a bad move obviously.

**Second issue:** The reason I had to use custom locking in the first place was because record-level locking wasn't working as expected (despite being properly configured). It was still using page-level locking. This was due to a performance trick I was using from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942824%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The trick involves opening a connection to the database where your linked tables are contained, which speeds up linked table operations. The problem is that the OpenDatabase method is NOT compatible with record-level locking so it opens the db using page-level locking, and since the first user to open a database determines its lock level (as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189633(v=office.10).aspx), all subsequent connections were forced to page-level.

**Third issue:** My problem is that my forms are not just simple bound forms to a single table. They open a single record (not allowing the user to navigate) and provide several functions which allow the user make modifications which affect other records in other tables that are related to the record they're editing (through comboboxes and pop-up forms and what not). As a result, I can't allow two people to open the same record at the same time as it leaves way too many opportunities for users to walk over each others' changes. So even if I remove the OpenDatabase performance trick, I'd still have to force the Form to be Dirty as soon as they open it so the record locks immediately and no one else can open it. I don't know if this would be as instantaneous as my custom locking and haven't yet tested that aspect.

In any event, I need a record to be locked the instant a user opens it and for now I've decided to keep using my custom locking (with the fix for the transaction). If something else comes to light that makes that less than ideal, I can try removing the OpenDatabase trick and switching to Access's built-in locking and force an immediate lock on every record when it is opened.

Comment: Note “open database” by row locking does not change nor matter what code and how you open the database (including your persistent connection). Once configured then setting DOES NOT change locking features in ANY way. Setting simple forces ANY and ALL edits via recordsets or SQL updates to expand the one record to a full page size (and thus you fake row locking). Setting does not change how locking works but forces all edits to expand any record to a full page size – even when NOT using locking. This setting thus is a huge source of bloat but results in all user edits receiving their own page.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you're saying here.

Comment: The post is to correct your claims of page locking. It does not matter nor change how the ACE engine will use record "size" editing for a database page.  You stated opening the database with a persistent connection that this disabled or caused row locking to not work - that is simply not the case. So I was just correcting some of your false and incorrect and misleading statements in pubic here. So you have errors in your claims here and that will mislead the public. So even if  you don't use any locking at all - checking the row locking box will expand all edits to one page size.

Comment: And yet, opening a persistent connection using OpenDatabase at app load does force page-locking on all Forms opened thereafter, even if you have record-locking turned on. You can test this for yourself.

Comment: Sure - If you create a new database object (DAO), then you not loading the Access settings and the Access settings are not used at all. So using VB6, vb.net etc. + dao, then you don’t get use of the row locking feature (so any separate instance of DAO used does not allow nor have row locking feature – never did). And if such a instance opens the database then you don’t get row locking. If you open any linked table for that persistent connection, then yes the settings are used. Once done then even using opendatabase will still respect the row locking feature.

Comment: I'm confused as to which part of my answer you're trying to correct then, because it sounds like you're saying the same thing now. If you create a database object and instantiate it using OpenDatabase (which is what the performance trick in the page I linked to says to do), it will impose page-level locking on all subsequent connections to linked tables in that same database.

Comment: The point is don't create the persistent with opendatabase - open a hidden form, or a global recordset to any  backend table. In other words you can create a persistent connection and not effect your locking settings. So you not stuck and you can create a persistent connection - we misleading everyone that a persistent connection can't be made to achieve row locking.

Answer (score 4):

It not clear why you only receiving “page” locking.

If you turn on row locking in file->options, then you ALSO need to set the particular form to lock the current record. So just turning on record locking will not help you. That setting ONLY sets the default for new forms - it is not a system wide setting.

If you correctly turn on locking for a form, then if two users are viewing the same record and one user starts to edit the record, then all others CANNOT edit the record. Any other user attempting to edit a record will see a “lock” icon in the record selector bar (assuming record selector is turned on for the given form). They also will receive a "beep" if they try to type into any editable control on the given form.

And when they try to edit, they will see a visible "lock" icon on the selector bar like this:

[image]

A few things:

If two users are able to edit a record, then you not have turned on locking for that given form. This feature MUST be set on a form-by-form basis. Changing the setting in file->options->client setting ONLY SETS THE DEFAULT for NEW forms you create! So the setting ONLY applies to the default for new forms – it does NOT change existing forms.

So setting record locking is ONLY a form-by-form setting.

So you ALWAYS MUST set each form you want locking to the current edited record. You set this in form design, in the data tab of the properties sheet like this:

[image]

And also keep in mind that the setting of record level locking (a different setting and feature) is an Access client setting and does NOT travel with the given application.

So since you state that two users can edit the same record, then CLEARLY you NEVER turned on record locking for that given form. The systemwide “default” record locking ONLY sets the above form default (so existing forms you have are NOT changed).

Next up:
The setting of [x] Open database by using record-level locking is an Access client setting and NOT saved with the application. So this is an Access-wide setting, not an application setting, nor one that travels with the application.

So you have to set this on each client workstation, or you have to set this in your start-up code.

If you can’t go around and change each workstation to change this setting (or you are using the Access runtime), then you can use this VBA in your start-up code to set this feature:

```
  Application.SetOption "Use Row Level Locking", True
```

Note that the setting does NOT take effect until exit the application, but that’s really a “non” issue since this means the first time you run this code, some users might well be in page locking mode, and others in row locking mode. Most of the time this causes little issue.

However the next time any user launches the application then they will be in row locking mode.

I have in the past also written custom locking code. And can outline how to make this work well, but from what you posted so far, you never turned on or set locking nor had locking working correctly for any of the forms you have now anyway.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of all of this. As I stated in the OP, I was originally using Access's built-in record locking, but this didn't work. It wouldn't just lock the record, it would lock a page of them. I did everything you laid out in your post: I set the application-level "Default record locking" setting to "Edited Record" and checked "Open databases by using record-level locking". I also set all of my forms to have a Form-level "Record Locks" property of "Edited Record". This still locked a page instead just the one record. I tested it extensively before abandoning the method.

Comment: Not that any of that mattered because Access's record locking doesn't kick in until they start *changing* the record, which is no good. They could have the record open and be browsing through it (without having made a change) and someone else could open it then and now two people have it open, and once that happens I'm already screwed. There are several ways they can modify values *related* to that record that will be overwritten once the last person who has that record open saves it. So even if I could solve the page-locking issue, it wouldn't help.

Comment: What I need is an INSTANTANEOUS way to lock a record so that every other user connecting to that db knows that someone else has it open. It doesn't matter if they've made any changes at all. Once it's OPEN, I need it locked.

Comment: Well, the locking is instant. So while you state that record locking did not work, you need to re-test as there no reason I can think as to why such locking did not work. Taking 100% different path seems of little use since the locking should work - you need to find out why.
While two people can view the record, which user do you want to have a lock on that record? I would think and assume that other users should be “read” only. This is exactly how it currently works now. I guess the issue you have to solve is who do you grant the lock, and what will other users receive?

Comment: What kind of UI you present to the users will be difficult. I mean, if two users are viewing a record, which one do you want to grant to the lock to? (or are you suggesting that others users can't view the record?). I also strongly suggest that modifying the record for purposes of a lock is a "bad" idea. You can certainly build your own locking system - but it should be "global", and work for all forms that can edit all tables - not just some custom column for one table. You can achieve this by creating a lock table. The lock column as text can then be tableName*PKID as a uniqure index.

Comment: I'm not sure how to be any clearer. Access's built-in record locking doesn't "kick in" until they start editing the record NOT when they open the form, ergo it is not instantaneous. That record locking also locks a page, not just a record, and I have tested this extensively. What I currently have in place, as I mentioned in the OP, is a field that the FIRST user to open the form populates with their username. This lets everyone else know who has it "locked". Anyone trying to open it after that has an open to view it Read-Only.

Comment: The issue I have to solve is that the population of the field that lets other users know who has it locked is not INSTANTANEOUS. It takes several seconds for users on other machines to "see" the username in that field, and during that time another user can open the form as if it isn't locked. I had considered making a separate table for locks in the hopes that this will solve my "lag" issue with the field not being updated right away, but if a single field on a table incurs a delay before other users can see the update, the same is probably true of a table update. I will probably test anyway.

Comment: An indexed column that is a concatenated string of tablename*ID will of course lock instant – your “locking” routines will have to grant a lock before displaying the record since you want to lock for first user viewing, not the first editing. I can’t see how this will be practical or work since if 1 is editing, and then when done and exits, then WHICH of the 3 others viewing are to get the lock now? And why grant it to someone only viewing and who now on a coffee break? (so 2 other users can’t edit who actually want to!). So which of the 3 read only users will you grant the lock to?

Comment: In regards to page vs row locking, clearly you not done much of any testing. I spent 15 years posting in the on-line community, was a technical editor for the Access 2010 developers reference, and been a Access MVP for Microsoft over 13 years. You are the FIRST PERSON in 17 years to make such a claim that row locking does not work. So you stand rather alone in this regards and this is a rather significant red flag in regards to your claim that row locking does not work.

Comment: It's practical because if I can get it working, then only one person gets the lock. Any subsequent users either can't open the record, or can only open it read only. No one "gets" the lock after the first user is done. I grant it to the first user to avoid all the problems that come with not locking it right away when someone starts viewing it. If they go on a break, the other users know who has it locked and they can tell them to exit the record.

Comment: And regardless of what should happen, what *does* happen is that the record is not instantly locked. There are a few seconds between the UPDATE statement (by the first user to open it) before the change to the record is "visible" by all of the other users. In that time, it's possible for a second person to open the same record.

Comment: Also, your bona-fides are great and all, but as long as we're throwing them around, I've been coding in Access for 20 years. I know how to check a box that says "Use row-level locking". I know how to turn on recording locking on a form. I've done all of this, and yet, when I lock record ID #1 by editing it and then try to open record ID #2 on another machine, it tells me that #2 is locked, even though #1 is the only one being edited. Record-level locking is not working for some reason that neither you nor I have ascertained. If you doubt me, I will be happy to provide you with a demonstration.

Comment: OK, I've discovered the issue with row-level locking, and it is two-fold. First, I have been using a technique to speed up linked table access (found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942824%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which involves opening an unused connection to the linked database using OpenDatabase. But according to this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189633(v=office.10).aspx), the first connection to the database determines the locking (regardless of how other connections are set). So the helper connection was doing the page-locking.

Comment: Second, my custom-locking process uses an UPDATE to set a LockedBy field before opening the record, but according to this: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189633(v=office.10).aspx) queries that UPDATE records CAN'T use row-level locking (even if the machine is configured to do so). So when rec #1 was being edited, and my process tried to UPDATE rec #2 to lock it, it failed because it tried to lock that whole page while doing the UPDATE. The result is that I cannot combine my custom locking procedure with row-level locking which I was hoping to do to cover as many bases as possible.

Comment: So the issue is that row-level locking only applies to certain aspects of operation in Access (not DAO 3.5 or earlier, not OpenDatabase, not DML queries, etc). If you're doing a very basic "open a simple form" process, it should work fine, but if you're doing anything more complex, it does you no good. In my case, I don't see a way to make use of it in a way that doesn't cause issues.

Comment: You not answered after first person is done editing and exited the form, then how do you plan to grant the lock to the 3 others that are still viewing the record as read only? After first is done, then which of the other 3 users currently viewing the record are you going to grant the lock to? (you have to outline what is going to occur here). The code + table to “grant” the lock not based on the table being editing by the form (you thus don’t even need any locking turned on). You use a recordset to maintain the lock table and the unique index on column of tablename*ID does the dirty work.

Comment: I answered that above. I said that no one gets the lock when the first user is done. It's not a necessary feature. If someone else is in it too long, they can just go tell them to exit. I don't follow the rest of that. I already don't have any locking turned on right now because I'm using my own custom locking. I'm using a field in the table itself instead of a separate table. I can test to see if a separate table makes any difference, but if the update isn't detected instantaneously by all users I'd be stuck with the same problem that I have now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the method described here:

[Handle concurrent update conflicts in Access silently](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/25780/Handle-concurrent-update-conflicts-in-Access-silently.html)

to handle your lock field.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work as it relies on the EditMode property. This doesn't prevent another user from opening the form (or even making an Edit) just because someone else it editing it on another machine. Originally, when I tried to implement "locking", I would run a test by calling rs.Edit, and if that threw an error, then I knew someone else was editing the record. The problem is that the record isn't locked for editing until they make a change to one of the fields, not when they first open the form.

Comment: Even manually calling rs.Edit on the machine that first opens the record doesn't truly put it in Edit mode (they have to make a physical change to a field). So if they're just browsing around the record for a bit without making changes, someone else could open it without rs.Edit throwing an exception on another machine. And once two people have the same record open, I'm pretty much doomed (there are numerous functions on the form that allow them to modify records in other tables that are related to the record they're viewing).

Comment: Also, this leaves me back with my original issue of not being able to use Access's built-in record locking because it locks an entire "page" of records instead of just the individual record itself (meaning several other records that aren't being edited will be inaccessible as well).

Comment: Access should not lock the page if you set row locking. As I pointed out in my response below, if the lock setting on a form is correctly set, then other users cannot start editing that record.

Comment: Yes, I only had your idea of marking the record as being edited in mind. @AlbertD.Kallal's extensive explanation should provide the answer for you.

Comment: This is a link only answer

Answer (score 0):

Since Access doesn't make locking records easy, I'm wondering if you were to add a table with locked record entries whether that would solve the problem even though it would be the "duct tape, soup can and coat hanger" solution:  You create a "Locked_Record" table with 2 fields a) record ID being updated and b) the user name of the person updating that record.  That table would control exactly who owns and therefore can edit what record.  Your form would have a search field and when the search term is entered and "Enter" pressed the form would search for the record by looking for it in the data and looking for it in the Locked_Record table.  If found in the Locked_Record table, then you user gets an error saying "Record in use already" and display who owns the record.  If not found in the data then the appropriate message is displayed.  If found in the data and not found in the Locked_Record table, then a Locked_Record entry would be created and the user would then get the data displayed in the form.  At this point nobody else can edit that record.  When the user is done updating, either the user would need to press a button saying "Done updating" or the form would have to be closed.  Either way the Locked_Record entry would be deleted so others could use that record.  If the record owner doesn't close out the form or doesn't press the button then that is a training issue.  This method could be user for multiple entities such as Customers, Employees, Departments, etc.  You would just have to assure your application and DB is set up so any sub-forms used which might lock other tables would ONLY affect that record's entries in the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but the information here inspired me to to use the following.  Basically, the me.txtApplication is a text box on the bound form.  The form is bound to the table and is set to lock the edited record in the property section.  This code won't do anything other than trigger that editing lock and promptly undo the change.  If another user tries to load the same record it will attempt to do the same edit, trigger the error, and move to the next record or start a new record without the user being the wiser.

```
'Lock current record with edit-level lock by editing and removing the edit from a 
field.
'If record is already locked, move to next record.

On Error Resume Next
Me.txtApplication = Me.txtApplication & "-%$^$^$$@#$"
Me.txtApplication = Replace(Me.txtApplication, "-%$^$^$$@#$", "")

If Err.Number = -2147352567 Then
    If Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount Then
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
    Else
        MsgBox "No available records.", vbOKOnly, "No Records"
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        '[If the condition is not true, then we are on the last record, so don't go 
to the next one]
    End If
End If

End Sub
```