# Can multiple users edit an Access database at the same time?

Tags: ms-access, multiple-users

We work with a large Access database and we want a few users (max. 5 to 6 at the worst) to be able to edit tables at the same time by using forms. We have split the database into front end and back end. The BE is placed on a NAS and each user has an offline copy of the FE on his own desktop. 
All users have full permissions and we switched the options (client settings -> Advanced) to the following settings: 
Default open mode: Shared
Default record locking: Edited record
Open databases by using record-level locking: yes
Encryption method: use legacy encryption (good for multi-user databases).

In the forms we also changed the property ‘record locks’ to ‘edited record’.

What we want to achieve is that when a user change a certain record in a form, other users can’t change the same record until the changes of the first user are saved. We also want to see a lock icon in the selector bar, as mentioned in this forum:
[Instantly "locking" a record in multi-user Access environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827351/instantly-locking-a-record-in-multi-user-access-environment)

For the moment we have done several tests, but we are unable to generate any “Writing conflict” when implementing the above, contrary to the numerous reports on the opposite behaviour one can find reported in the internet and the documentation of Access. The first user changes a record and the second user is still able to change it, without any particular notification in the sense of a selector bar icon or a “writing conflict”, and the user that closes the database the latest takes it all (all changes by the first user are overruled).

Can anyone explain me what we are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the locking on a form by form basis. So changing the client settings to "edited" record will ONLY become the default for new forms you create.

So, to set locking for a form to edited record, you MUST set EACH form you have to Edited record. Once you do this, then additional users attempting to edit the same reocrd will see + receive a lock icon in the selector bar. They only will see this bar WHEN they attempt to start editing, but if you set form to "edited" record, then this should work fine.

The "over all" settings you are playing with don't change anything here (well except the option to open databases as shared - but that's already the default and already a given since more then one user is able to edit the data.

So change the form in question locking setting to "edited" record. You now have record locking setup for that one form. Settings for record locking are a form by form setting - the other settings really don't matter.