# Multiple users accessing a linked table occasionally see a message "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only"

Tags: vba, ms-access

We have a split MS Access database. When users log on, they are connected/linked to two separate Access database (one for the specific project they are working on and one for record locking (and other global settings)). The "locking" database is the one I need to find a solution for.

One of the tables "tblTS_RecordLocking", simply stores a list of user names and the recordID of the record they are editing. This never has more than 50 records - usually being closer to 5-10. But before a user can do anything on a record, it opens "tblTS_RecordLocking" to see if the record is in use (so it happens a lot):

`Set recIOC = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblTSS_RecordLocking.* FROM tblTSS_RecordLocking WHERE (((tblTSS_RecordLocking.ProjectID_Lock)=1111) AND ((tblTSS_RecordLocking.RecordID_Lock)=123456));", , dbReadOnly)`

If it's in use, the user simply gets a message and the form/record remains locked.  If not in use, it will close the recordset and re-open it so that the user name is updated with the Record ID:

```
Set recIOC = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblTSS_RecordLocking.* FROM tblTSS_RecordLocking WHERE (((tblTSS_RecordLocking.UserName_Lock)='John Smith'));")
If recIOC.EOF = True Then
    recIOC.AddNew
    recIOC.Fields![UserName_Lock] = "John Smith"
Else
    recIOC.Edit
End If

    recIOC.Fields![RecordID_Lock] = 123456
    recIOC.Fields![ProjectID_Lock] = 111

recIOC.Update
recIOC.Close: set recIOC=Nothing
```

As soon as this finishes, everything realting to the second database is closed down (and the .laccdb file disappears).

So here's the problem. On very rare occasions, a user can get a message:

**3027 - Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.**

On even rarer occasions, it can flag the db as corrrupt needing to be compressed and re-indexed.

I really want to know the most reliable way to do the check/update.  The process may run several hundred times in a day, and whilst I only see the issue once every few weeks, and for the most part handle it cleanly (on the front-end), I'm sure there is a better, more reliable way.

Comment: I've never encountered this technique of managing record locking. Why have tblTS_RecordLocking in a separate database? Any help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827351/instantly-locking-a-record-in-multi-user-access-environment

Comment: Essentially, there are numerous project / .accdb databases, which the users switch between.  But, we also have the second global database to handle permissions, settings and record locking (across all projects). That being said, I have just realised that moving tblTSS_RecordLocking into each project, would stop the need to constantly open/close the global database, which may help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'constantly open/close'? If tables are linked db does not open/close. Not sure moving table to each project backend will resolve timing issue. And if you ever wanted to modify that table, the effort would be magnified.

Comment: It's a fair point. However, the question still remains. We need a table to store which records are being edited.  This isn't only to stop users editing the same record at the same time, but also to prevent Admin functions updating data that is being edited.  So, I still need to find a bullet proof way to open/check/edit a single (small) record.

Comment: If you get this error and the database gets corrupted sometimes, please check the quality of the connection to the backend. It seems tiny dropdowns happen causing this issue (some times it drops while writing data and this corrupts the database). It is clear on this particular database because, as you mentioned, it is extensively accessed so network is polled regularly.

Comment: That makes sense as we have a new server being setup and the exxisting server, whilst it is well within capacity, could be the cause.  But again, going back to the original question. Is there a safer way to do what I am doing?

Comment: Unfortunately if this is the case the only solution to do it safely is to migrate to MS SQL. This is one of the purposes of MS SQL as it uses Transaction Log to avoid such damages to database due to network glitches.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mamadsp that moving to SQL is the best option and am already in the process of doing this.  However, whilst I was not able to create a fix for this issue, I was able to find a work-around that has yet to fail.

Instead of having a single lock table in the global database.  I found that creating a lock table in the project database solved the problem.  The main benefit of this is that there are much fewer activities on the table. So, not perfect - but it is stable.